# add to Arraylist for each instances

Tags: java, arraylist

Fairly I am a very beginner in Java, I assume there must be the solution of my issue because it is very easy to solve I guess, however I did not find, if anybody can give the link and direct answer, that would be really great.

I have two classes, one is `Creation`, another one is `slice`. Now `Creation` class has multiple instances of the `slice` class which is based on the ActionPerformed by the JButton component.

Now I want to create an `ArrayList` of the slices [in the `slice` class], every time the instance is called from `creation` class. In the beginning the Arraylist would be empty. Then I want to get the panel from the arraylist back to the `Creation` class using the index of the arraylist.

```
    public class Slice extends JPanel {


        public ArrayList<Slice> network_slices;
        private JPanel slice;

        public Slice() {


            network_slices = new ArrayList<>();
            slice= new JPanel();
            slice.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 600));
            slice.setVisible(true);
            network_slices.add((Slice) slice);
        }

        public JPanel getPanel() {
        //What to do to get the Panel in Creation class using their array index?
        }

    }
```

Comment: Having a class and variable both named `Slice` is extremely confusing.

Comment: I edited your code to name variable with lowercase letters.

Comment: Thank you so much for edit this

Answer (score 0):

before return in getPanel() add:

```
network_slices.add(slice);
```

Comment: Should I write like this , network_slices.add((Slice) slice) ?

Comment: "The method add(Slice) in the type ArrayList<Slice> is not applicable for the arguments (JPanel)",

Answer (score 0):

Try this out?

```
public class Slice extends JPanel {

   public ArrayList<Slice> network_slices;
   private JPanel slice;

   public Slice() {
      network_slices = new ArrayList<>();
   }

   public JPanel getPanel() {
      slice = new JPanel();
      slice.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 600));
      slice.setVisible(true);
      network_slices.add((Slice) slice);
      return slice;
   }
}
```

Please dont mess up with naming conventions:

- `Slice` is the name of class. Always starts with a capital letter.
- `slice` is the name of variable. Always starts with a small letter.

Moreover in Java we all are used to CamelCase. So your variable should be named `nerworkSlices` instead of `network_slices`. But just a little thing. The above is more imporant. Also the diamond operator in JDK 7 can be used instead of explicit type parameters like `new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting this error. "The method add(Slice) in the type ArrayList<Slice> is not applicable for the arguments (JPanel)"

Comment: Edited, you have to cast `(Slice) slice`